Stripping Text From A String Power Automate Desktop
I was looking for an answer to the question above and could only find answers similar to this post here: 'How can I remove text from a string in PowerAutomate?' by Marley (I did want to ask this question in the comment section of that post but can't due to low reputation) but that post asks about Power Automate, the online Microsoft service, whereas I am making a program with Power Automate Desktop.
I want to have a user input a string and it interoperates that as a number. The message box asks the user for a size in GB and I want it to strip any form of text from the string and then use it later. I tried the "Trim Text" feature but this doesn't work since I have to input exact quotes for removing, which could be a lot of things. I also tried "Convert String to Number" but this throws an error as it has non-numeric characters inside the string.
I know that "Trim Text" can have special characters such as £%/ etc but I don't know what the list of characters are or what they do, and I'm unsure how to formulate that into a question for Google.

can you provide an example of an input you use and the expected output ?

So it should be a number followed by possibly GB, MB, KB, TB, basicly formats of storage types, but I want it to complete remove all text and just keep the numbers
